# Matlab euclidean pairwise square distance function

Tags: matlab

I have a 60000 by 300 matrix call `X`. I am trying to find pairwise euclidean distances. I know that the `pdist` function in matlab (stats toolbox) can do this. However, when I type in the code `pdist(X)`, I get the following error message:

```
Error using pdistmex
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in pdist (line 252)
    Y = pdistmex(X',dist,additionalArg);
```

Any advice for fixes? Is the matrix size too big?

Comment: You have exactly `nchoosek(6e4,2)` = 1799970000 pairwise combinations which total to 1799970000 * 8 bytes ~ 13.4108216 gigabytes

Comment: Is it bad that I did that calculation in wolframalpha? :)

Comment: It would be better to sit down and think why you want such distances. Is it to find a minimum/maximum? Perhaps calculating them on demand would be wiser...

Answer (score 1):

Simply put yes, the `pdist` method is hungry for your memory and your computer cannot feed it. For example, even with a 6000 by 300 matrix X, I get the following variable sizes for X and Y using `whos X Y`:

```
>> whos X Y
  Name         Size                      Bytes  Class     Attributes

  X         6000x300                  14400000  double              
  Y            1x17997000            143976000  double
```

Now my my memory states (on a 32 bit machine):

```
>> memory
        Maximum possible array:             677 MB (7.101e+008 bytes) *
```

So I am really pushing the memory limits with the computation `Y = pdist(X)` as this produces an array of roughly 1.44 *10^8 bytes whereas the maximum possible array size is roughly of order 5 times that. Any bigger with the matrix and your system might not be happy. Your matrix of 60000 by 300 will produce a Y array of 179970000 values!

There might be workarounds if you really need to compute the Euclidian distance of a matrix this size, if so, I might be able to help you more...

Comment: Hrm... yea I am trying to code spectral clustering for certain types of image segmentation. Part of the code requires this sort of pairwise Euclidean distance. I tried hard coding this function, but matlab takes hours to days to run... Is there a faster workaround?

Comment: I see. Throw this on the overflow as a new question.

Comment: @voxeloctree: I almost didn't see the difference there, 6e3 (your example) vs. 6e4 (OP's data) :)

Comment: Right, it was to produce an example that the OP could do themselves to get the grasp of memory strain of pdist.