# Fast Algorithms for Finding Pairwise Euclidean Distance (Distance Matrix)

Tags: matlab, vectorization, linear-algebra

I know matlab has a built in pdist function that will calculate pairwise distances. However, my matrix is so large that its 60000 by 300 and matlab runs out of memory.

This question is a follow up on [Matlab euclidean pairwise square distance function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756265/matlab-euclidean-pairwise-square-distance-function/17756481?noredirect=1#comment25925503_17756481).

Is there any workaround for this computational inefficiency. I tried manually coding the pairwise distance calculations and it usually takes a full day to run (sometimes 6 to 7 hours).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is never going to be *quick*.  You have ~2e9 results to calculate, each of which requires 300 multiplications, and 600 additions/subtractions.  So approximately 2e12 operations in total.

Comment: That said, it ought to be possible to do significantly better than 6-7 hours, with sufficiently-optimised code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - the only way to know that is to know more about the computer being used. How much RAM?

Comment: @woodchips: That's a fair point; the output array is ~16GB (I guess I'm used to working on machines with 96GB RAM.)  However, even if the output was being written directly to disk, a typical write speed of 50MB/s would only take 5 minutes or so...

Comment: A better investment of your time and effort might be to find a decent 64-bit machine with plenty of RAM running 64-bit Matlab and run your code on it (locally or remotely). Do you have any friends with a Mac and Matlab? It takes only 8 minutes and 45 seconds (and 14,399,760,000 bytes of memory) to run `d=pdist(rand(6e4,3e2));` on my Retina MacBook Pro with Matlab R2012b and OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: @horchler - While I completely agree with your comment, the issue is always that if this person manages to make this problem run in a reasonable time, the next problem will have 10 times as much data unless they recognize the limits of the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's good to know the limits, but pointing them out doesn't necessarily solve a problem or answer a question. One must also be pragmatic. The user has data to analyze. Maybe they'll have 10 times as much the next time. Maybe not. ... So, there are limits. The problem is a big one, but some of the tools are a bit anemic (the PC). How would *you* go about solving this?

Comment: There are PhDs in Combinatorics, i.e. it takes more than a question on SO to sove this type of question, unless you describe the type of problem you want to solve, think how to properly tackle it and eventually approach a smarter brute force scheme.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I couldn't resist playing around. I created a Matlab [mex C file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-interfaces-for-c-c-fortran-com.html) called [`pdistc`](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/01/pdistc.c) that implements pairwise Euclidean distance for single and double precision. On my machine using Matlab R2012b and R2015a it's 20–25% faster than [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html)(and the underlying `pdistmex` helper function) for large inputs (e.g., 60,000-by-300).

As has been pointed out, this problem is fundamentally bounded by memory and you're asking for a lot of it. My mex C code uses minimal memory beyond that needed for the output. In comparing its memory usage to that of `pdist`, it looks like the two are virtually the same. In other words, `pdist` is not using lots of extra memory. Your memory problem is likely in the memory used up before calling `pdist` (can you use `clear` to remove any large arrays?) or simply because you're trying to solve a big computational problem on tiny hardware.

So, my `pdistc` function likely won't be able to save you memory overall, but you may be able to use another feature I built in. You can calculate chunks of your overall pairwise distance vector. Something like this:

```
m = 6e3;
n = 3e2;
X = rand(m,n);
sz = m*(m-1)/2;

for i = 1:m:sz-m
    D = pdistc(X', i, i+m); % mex C function, X is transposed relative to pdist
    ...                     % Process chunk of pairwise distances
end
```

This is considerably slower (10 times or so) and this part of my C code is not optimized well, but it will allow much less memory use – assuming that you don't need the entire array at one time. Note that you could do the same thing much more efficiently with `pdist` (or `pdistc`) by creating a loop where you passed in subsets of `X` directly, rather than all of it.

If you have a 64-bit Intel Mac, you won't need to compile as I've included the `.mexmaci64` binary, but otherwise you'll need to figure out how to compile the code for your machine. I can't help you with that. It's possible that you may not be able to get it to compile or that there will be compatibility issues that you'll need to solve by editing the code yourself. It's also possible that there are bugs and the code will crash Matlab. Also, note that you may get slightly different outputs relative to `pdist` with differences between the two in the range of machine epsilon ([`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)). `pdist` may or may not do fancy things to avoid overflows for large inputs and other numeric issues, but be aware that my code does not.

Additionally, I created a simple [pure Matlab implementation](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/01/pdistq.m). It is massively slower than the mex code, but still faster than a naïve implementation or the code found in `pdist`.

All of the files [can be found here](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/01/). The ZIP archive includes all of the files. It's BSD licensed. Feel free to optimize (I tried BLAS calls and OpenMP in the C code to no avail – maybe some pointer magic or GPU/OpenCL could further speed it up). I hope that it can be helpful to you or someone else.

Answer (score 5):

On my system the following is the fastest (Even faster than the C code `pdistc` by @horchler):

```
function [ mD ] = CalcDistMtx ( mX )    
  vSsqX = sum(mX .^ 2);
  mD = sqrt(bsxfun(@plus, vSsqX.', vSsqX) - (2 * (mX.' * mX)));       
end
```

You'll need a very well tuned C code to beat this, I think.

**Update**
Since [MATLAB R2016b MATLAB supports implicit broadcasting](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) without the use of [`bsxfun()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Hence the code can be written:

```
function [ mD ] = CalcDistMtx ( mX )    
  vSsqX = sum(mX .^ 2, 1);
  mD = sqrt(vSsqX.'+ vSsqX - (2 * (mX.' * mX)));       
end
```

A generalization is given in my [Calculate Distance Matrix project](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/CalcDistanceMatrix).

P. S.
Using MATLAB's `pdist` for comparison: `squareform(pdist(mX.'))` is equivalent to `CalcDistMtx(mX)`.
Namely the input should be transposed.

Comment: In the current function, mX is a K by N matrix, where K is the number of variables and N is the number of observation. The usual notation is the transpose of this, so be careful!

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181392.

Answer (score 0):

Computers are not infinitely large, or infinitely fast. People think that they have a lot of memory, a fast CPU, so they just create larger and larger problems, and then eventually wonder why their problem runs slowly. The fact is, this is NOT computational inefficiency. It is JUST an overloaded CPU.

As Oli points out in a comment, there are something like 2e9 values to compute, even assuming you only compute the upper or lower half of the distance matrix. (6e4^2/2 is approximately 2e9.) This will require roughly 16 gigabytes of RAM to store, assuming that only ONE copy of the array is created in memory. If your code is sloppy, you might easily double or triple that. As soon as you go into virtual memory, things get much slower.

Wanting a big problem to run fast is not enough. To really help you, we need to know how much RAM is available. Is this a virtual memory issue? Are you using 64 bit MATLAB, on a CPU that can handle all the needed RAM?

Comment: Careful on the misleading wording there; one does not "go into virtual memory", one is always using virtual memory... ;)

Comment: true, modern computers are always using virtual memory (each process is given a contiguous virtual address space of the maximum size the OS/architecture allows). What you want to be careful about is paging/thrashing

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, et al.: You might be interested in my new answer to this question. Slightly faster than Matlab's `pdist`.