# Vectorizing double for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a matrix `A` that contains 24 values for each day of the year (one value for each hour). Each column of `A` is a different day and each day has 24 rows worth of data (`A` is 24-by-365). I want to compare each day to each other by comparing the hour data of each day. To do this, I take one column of data and compare it to the next column. I take the difference of each hour's data in the two columns and then square and sum them to get a single value indicating how similar the two days are. I then do this with every possible combination of days, creating a 365-by-365 matrix, `d`, indicating how similar each day is to each other day. For example, element `d(20,100)` contains a value indicating how similar the 20th day of the year is to the 100th. The code is working, but it is quite slow and I would like to be able to vectorize it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for j=1:365
    for k=1:365
        d(j,k)=sqrt(sum((A(:,j)-A(:,k)).^2));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pairwise Euclidean distance using [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html), which does the heavy-lifting in C, and [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) to create the [distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix):

```
d = squareform(pdist(A.'));
```

If you need this to be even faster (365-by-365 is not very big though), see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799550/2278029) or try this [File Exchange program](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18937-ipdm-inter-point-distance-matrix).

Answer (score 4):

You can't beat [horchler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17932279/1714410), but for completeness here's how this can be done using `bsxfun`

```
d = bsxfun(@minus, permute(A, [3 2 1]), permute(A, [2 1 3]));
d = sqrt( sum( d.^2, 3 ) );
```

Another nice way of doing this is using the fact that `|| x - y || = sqrt(||x||^2-2< x,y >+||y||^2)`. Therefore

```
n = sum(A.^2, 1); % norm of each vector
b = bsxfun(@plus, n, n') - 2 * A' * A;
```