# Julia vs. MATLAB - Distance Matrix - Run Time Test

Tags: matlab, performance, julia, linear-algebra

I started learning Julia not a long time ago and I decided to do a simple 
comparison between Julia and Matlab on a simple code for computing Euclidean
distance matrices from a set of high dimensional points.

The task is simple and can be divided into two cases:

**Case 1:** Given two datasets in the form of n x d matrices, say X1 and X2, compute the pair wise Euclidean distance between each point in X1 and all the  points in X2. If X1 is of size n1 x d, and X2 is of size n2 x d, then the resulting Euclidean distance matrix D will be of size n1 x n2. In the general setting, matrix D is not symmetric, and diagonal elements are not equal to zero.

**Case 2:** Given one dataset in the form of n x d matrix X, compute the pair wise Euclidean distance between all the n points in X. The resulting Euclidean distance matrix D will be of size n x n, symmetric, with zero elements on the main diagonal.

My implementation of these functions in Matlab and in Julia is given below. Note that none of the implementations rely on loops of any sort, but rather simple linear algebra operations. Also, note that the implementation using both languages is very similar.

My expectations before running any tests for these implementations is that the Julia code will be much faster than the Matlab code, and by a significant margin. To my surprise, this was not the case!

The parameters for my experiments are given below with the code. My machine is a MacBook Pro. (15" Mid 2015) with 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 (Quad Core), and 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

Matlab version: R2018a

Julia version:  0.6.3 
            BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
            LAPACK: libopenblas64_ 
            LIBM: libopenlibm 
            LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)

The results are given in Table (1) below.

Table 1: Average time in seconds (with standard deviation) over 30 trials for computing Euclidean distance matrices between two different datasets (Col. 1), 
and between all pairwise points in one dataset (Col. 2).

```
          Two Datasets  ||  One Dataset
```

---

Matlab:      2.68 (0.12) sec.      1.88 (0.04) sec.

Julia V1:      5.38 (0.17) sec.      4.74 (0.05) sec.

Julia V2:      5.2 (0.1) sec.

---

I was not expecting this significant difference between both languages. I expected Julia to be faster than Matlab, or at least, as fast as Matlab. It was really a surprise to see that Matlab is almost 2.5 times faster than Julia in this particular task. I didn't want to draw any early conclusions based on these results for few reasons.

***First***, while I think that my Matlab implementation is as good as it can be, I'm wondering whether my Julia implementation is the best one for this task. I'm still learning Julia and I hope there is a more efficient Julia code that can yield faster computation time for this task. In particular, where is the main bottleneck for Julia in this task? Or, why does Matlab have an edge in this case?

***Second***, my current Julia package is based on the generic and standard BLAS and LAPACK packages for MacOS. I'm wondering whether JuliaPro with BLAS and LAPACK based on Intel MKL will be faster than the current version I'm using. This is why I opted to get some feedback from more knowledgeable people on StackOverflow.

The ***third*** reason is that I'm wondering whether the compile time for Julia was
included in the timings shown in Table 1 (2nd and 3rd rows), and whether there is a better way to assess the execution time for a function.

I will appreciate any feedback on my previous three questions.

Thank you!

Hint: This question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question on StackOverflow. However, this is not entirely true. This question has three aspects as reflected by the answers below. First, yes, one part of the question is related to the comparison of OpenBLAS vs. MKL. Second, it turns out that the implementation as well can be improved as shown by one of the answers. And last, bench-marking the julia code itself can be improved by using BenchmarkTools.jl.

**MATLAB**

```
num_trials = 30;
dim = 1000;
n1 = 10000;
n2 = 10000;

T = zeros(num_trials,1);

XX1 = randn(n1,dim);
XX2 = rand(n2,dim);

%%% DIFEERENT MATRICES
DD2ds = zeros(n1,n2);

for (i = 1:num_trials)
  tic;
  DD2ds = distmat_euc2ds(XX1,XX2);
  T(i) = toc;
end

mt = mean(T);
st = std(T);

fprintf(1,'\nDifferent Matrices:: dim: %d, n1 x n2: %d x %d -> Avg. Time %f (+- %f) \n',dim,n1,n2,mt,st);

%%% SAME Matrix 
T = zeros(num_trials,1);

DD1ds = zeros(n1,n1);

for (i = 1:num_trials)
  tic;
  DD1ds = distmat_euc1ds(XX1);
  T(i) = toc;
end

mt = mean(T);
st = std(T);

fprintf(1,'\nSame Matrix:: dim: %d, n1 x n1 : %d x %d -> Avg. Time %f (+- %f) \n\n',dim,n1,n1,mt,st);
```

**distmat_euc2ds.m**

```
function [DD] = distmat_euc2ds (XX1,XX2)
    n1 = size(XX1,1);
    n2 = size(XX2,1);
    DD = sqrt(ones(n1,1)*sum(XX2.^2.0,2)' + (ones(n2,1)*sum(XX1.^2.0,2)')' - 2.*XX1*XX2');
end
```

**distmat_euc1ds.m**

```
function [DD] = distmat_euc1ds (XX)
    n1 = size(XX,1);
    GG = XX*XX';
    DD = sqrt(ones(n1,1)*diag(GG)' + diag(GG)*ones(1,n1) - 2.*GG);
end
```

**JULIA**

```
include("distmat_euc.jl")

num_trials = 30;

dim = 1000;
n1 = 10000;
n2 = 10000;

T = zeros(num_trials);

XX1 = randn(n1,dim)
XX2 = rand(n2,dim)

DD = zeros(n1,n2)

# Euclidean Distance Matrix: Two Different Matrices V1
# ====================================================
for i = 1:num_trials
    tic()
    DD = distmat_eucv1(XX1,XX2)
    T[i] = toq();
end

mt = mean(T)
st = std(T)

println("Different Matrices V1:: dim:$dim, n1 x n2: $n1 x $n2 -> Avg. Time $mt (+- $st)")


# Euclidean Distance Matrix: Two Different Matrices V2
# ====================================================
for i = 1:num_trials
    tic()
    DD = distmat_eucv2(XX1,XX2)
    T[i] = toq();
end

mt = mean(T)
st = std(T)

println("Different Matrices V2:: dim:$dim, n1 x n2: $n1 x $n2 -> Avg. Time $mt (+- $st)")


# Euclidean Distance Matrix: Same Matrix V1
# =========================================
for i = 1:num_trials
    tic()
    DD = distmat_eucv1(XX1)
    T[i] = toq();
end

mt = mean(T)
st = std(T)

println("Same Matrix V1:: dim:$dim, n1 x n2: $n1 x $n2 -> Avg. Time $mt (+- $st)")
```

**distmat_euc.jl**

```
function distmat_eucv1(XX1::Array{Float64,2},XX2::Array{Float64,2})
    (num1,dim1) = size(XX1)
    (num2,dim2) = size(XX2)

    if (dim1 != dim2)
        error("Matrices' 2nd dimensions must agree!")
    end

    DD = sqrt.((ones(num1)*sum(XX2.^2.0,2)') +
         (ones(num2)*sum(XX1.^2.0,2)')' - 2.0.*XX1*XX2');
end


function distmat_eucv2(XX1::Array{Float64,2},XX2::Array{Float64,2})
    (num1,dim1) = size(XX1)
    (num2,dim2) = size(XX2)

    if (dim1 != dim2)
        error("Matrices' 2nd dimensions must agree!")
    end

    DD = (ones(num1)*sum(Base.FastMath.pow_fast.(XX2,2.0),2)') +
         (ones(num2)*sum(Base.FastMath.pow_fast.(XX1,2.0),2)')' -
         Base.LinAlg.BLAS.gemm('N','T',2.0,XX1,XX2);

    DD = Base.FastMath.sqrt_fast.(DD)
end


function distmat_eucv1(XX::Array{Float64,2})
    n = size(XX,1)
    GG = XX*XX';
    DD = sqrt.(ones(n)*diag(GG)' + diag(GG)*ones(1,n) - 2.0.*GG)
end
```

Comment: Why would you expect Julia to be significantly faster? MatLab is explicitly designed to be fast at matrix algebra. TBH I suspect that most of what you are timing here is the difference between openblas and intel mkl blas for your specific architecture. (I think Matlab uses mkl from memory). However, if you want to delve into it more deeply, have a look at [ProfileView](https://github.com/timholy/ProfileView.jl) (on v0.6), and avoid worrying about compilation time etc by using `@btime` from the package [BenchmarkTools](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl)

Comment: Also, the [Distances](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl) package is a fantastic example of how to write good, fast, Julia code, so if you're looking to sharpen up your Julia skills, looking over the implementation of Euclidean distance in that package might be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Colin! these are indeed helpful tips.

Comment: Yes, @ColinTBowers is right. What you're measuring here is just the default BLAS installations, it's really nothing to do with either language itself. "USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell" is saying that your BLAS isn't fully optimized, described as "the objective of DYNAMIC_ARCH is to build the OpenBLAS library in a generic mode with moderate optimization for a wide range of possible architectures". Intel MKL might just be compiled to be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is MATLAB so fast in matrix multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication)

Comment: I modified the code as suggested by @DNF and I will post the new numbers below. Significant improvement! I believe that optimizing OpenBLAS or using Intel MKL will be the second aspect to consider now. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First question:** If I re-write the julia distance function like so:

```
function dist2(X1::Matrix, X2::Matrix)
    size(X1, 2) != size(X2, 2) && error("Matrices' 2nd dimensions must agree!")
    return sqrt.(sum(abs2, X1, 2) .+ sum(abs2, X2, 2)' .- 2 .* (X1 * X2'))
end
```

I shave >40% off the execution time.

For a single dataset you can save a bit more, like this:

```
function dist2(X::Matrix)
    G = X * X'
    dG = diag(G)
    return sqrt.(dG .+ dG' .- 2 .* G)
end
```

**Third question:** You should do your benchmarking with BenchmarkTools.jl, and perform the benchmarking like this (remember `$` for variable interpolation):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> @btime dist2($XX1, $XX2);
```

Additionally, you should not do powers using floats, like this: `X.^2.0`. It is faster, and equally correct to write `X.^2`.

For multiplication there is no speed difference between `2.0 .* X` and `2 .* X`, but you should still prefer using an integer, because it is more generic. As an example, if `X` has `Float32` elements, multiplying with `2.0` will promote the array to `Float64`s, while multiplying with `2` will preserve the eltype.

And finally, note that in new versions of Matlab, too, you can get broadcasting behaviour by simply adding `Mx1` arrays with `1xN` arrays. There is no need to first expand them by multiplying with `ones(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for all this thorough feedback! I tried your suggestions and here are the new results using the same benchmark I used earlier, just to be on the same ground.
For Julia:
 For two datasets: from 5.38 (0.17) to 2.57 (0.14)
 For one dataset : from 4.74 (0.05) to 2.45 (0.06) 

For Matlab:
 For two datasets: from 2.68 (0.12) to 2.17 (0.16)
 For one dataset : from 1.88 (0.04) to 1.85 (0.19)

Comment: I will look into BenchmarkTools and ProfileView (as suggested by @ColinTBowers ) and start using them.

Comment: Now, I believe the little differences between Julia and Matlab are really due to the differences between OpenBLAS and Intel MKL BLAS. I have two questions though: 1. Do you recommend any documentation/tutorials for writing fast code in Julia? 2. Are you aware of any clean documentation for optimizing open OpenBLAS and/or using Intel MKL BLAS instead of OpenBLAS with Julia? I will do my search but I'm wondering if there are already well known references out there. Thank again @DNF!

Comment: For general performance tips, the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/) is pretty good. One tip I keep in mind, and which is relevant for your code example, is to avoid creating unnecessary temporary arrays (`sum(sqrt, x)` instead of `sum(sqrt.(x))`), and avoid iterating over arrays twice if once is sufficient (very common in Matlab-like code). When using dot-broadcasting, make sure you dot _all_ the right places. As for question 2, I haven't played around with BLAS, so cannot help you there.