# MATLAB: bsxfun unclear. Want to accelerate minimum distance between segments

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

Using MATLAB,
Imagine a Nx6 array of numbers which represent N segments with 3+3=6 initial and end point coordinates.

Assume I have a `function Calc_Dist( Segment_1, Segment_2 )` that takes as input two 1x6 arrays, and that after some operations returns a scalar, namely the minimal euclidean distance between these two segments.

I want to calculate the pairwise minimal distance between all N segments of my list, but would like to avoid a double loop to do so.

I cannot wrap my head around the documentation of the **`bsxfun`** function of MATLAB, so I cannot make this work. For the sake of a minimal example (the distance calculation is obviously not correct):

```
function scalar = calc_dist( segment_1, segment_2 )
         scalar = sum( segment_1 + segment_2 )
end
```

and the main

```
Segments = rand( 1500, 6 )
Pairwise_Distance_Matrix = bsxfun( @calc_dist, segments, segments' )
```

Is there any way to do this, or am I forced to use double loops ?

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: bsxfun takes as argument a function `C = fun(A,B)` where `A`, `B`, `C` should have the same size. Is not the case for your function.

Comment: what if my function returns a 1 by 6 copy of the scalar, so that A,B and C have the same size ?

Comment: +1 for minimal example

Comment: @Mathusalem If you read carefully the requirements for `fun` argument of `bsxfun`, the function needs to accept arguments of *arbitrary* size, which is not your case again (because your args need to be 1x6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist.html) rather than `bsxfun`. `pdist` can be used in two different ways, the second of which is applicable to your problem:

- With built-in distance functions, supplied as strings, such as `'euclidean'`, `'hamming'` etc.
- With a custom distance function, a handle to which you supply.

In the second case, the distance function

> must be of the form
>
> ```
>      function D2 = distfun(XI, XJ),
> ```
>
> taking as arguments a `1`-by-`N` vector `XI` containing a single row of `X`, an
>       `M2`-by-`N` matrix `XJ` containing multiple rows of `X`, and returning an
>       `M2`-by-`1` vector of distances `D2`, whose `J`th element is the distance
>       between the observations `XI` and `XJ(J,:)`.

Although the documentation doesn't tell, it's very likely that the second way is not as efficient as the first (a double loop might even be faster, who knows), but you can use it. You would need to define your function so that it fulfills the stated condition. With your example function it's easy: *for this part* you'd use `bsxfun`:

```
function scalar = calc_dist( segment_1, segment_2 )
    scalar = sum(bsxfun(@plus, segment_1, segment_2), 2);
end
```

Note also that

- `pdist` works with rows (not columns), which is what you need.
- `pdist` reduces operations by exploiting the properties that any distance function must have. Namely, the distance of an element to itself is known to be zero; and the distance for each pair can be computed just once thanks to symmetry. If you want to arrange the output in the form of a matrix, use [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/squareform.html).

So, after your actual distance function has been modified appropriately (which may be the hard part), use:

```
distances = squareform(pdist(segments, @calc_dist));
```

For example:

```
N = 4;
segments = rand(N,6);
distances = squareform(pdist(segments, @calc_dist));
```

produces

```
distances =
         0    6.1492    7.0886    5.5016
    6.1492         0    6.8559    5.2688
    7.0886    6.8559         0    6.2082
    5.5016    5.2688    6.2082         0
```

Comment: The funny part is that, internally, `pdist` uses double loops to compute the pairwise distance. :-) Just `edit pdist` and look at the code around from line 250 onwards (I have access to Revision: 1.1.8.5)

Comment: @CST-Link It also says "Call a mex file to compute distances for the standard distance measures" (revision 1.1.8.2). That more or less confirms that it's faster with built-in distance functions

Comment: I skipped those lines... indeed, for the standard distances and non-sparse input, it will use the MEX function.

Comment: Thank you both Luis Mendo and CST-Link. In my mind you both provided an answer in which I learned something. I selected the answer at random :/

Comment: Your method accelerated my execution time by a factor 1.5

Comment: @Mathusalem: See [this question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777292/fast-algorithms-for-finding-pairwise-euclidean-distance) for further tips on speeding up `pdist` for calculating pairwise Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't see any "smarter" (i.e. read faster) solution than the double loop. For speed consideration I'd organize the points as a 6×*N* array, not the other way, because column access is way faster than row access in MATLAB.

So:

```
N = 150000;
Segments = rand(6, N);
Pairwise_Distance_Matrix = Inf(N, N);
for i = 1:(N-1)
        for j = (i+1):N
                Pairwise_Distance_Matrix(i,j) = calc_dist(Segments(:,i), Segments(:,j));
        end;
end;

Minimum_Pairwise_Distance = min(min(Pairwise_Distance_Matrix));
```

Contrary to common wisdom, explicit loops are faster now in MATLAB compared to the likes of `arrayfun`, `cellfun` or `structfun`; `bsxfun` beats everything else in terms of speed, but it doesn't apply to your case.