# Average for all elements in a row except the element itself - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, calculated-columns

For a given matrix A, how can i create a matrix B of the same size where every column is the mean (or any other function) of all the other columns?

example:
a function on

```
A = [
     1     1     1
     2     3     4
     4     5     6]
```

should result in

```
B = [ 
      1   1  1 
      3.5 3 2.5
      5.5 5 4.5]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perfect setup for `bsxfun` -

```
B = bsxfun(@minus,sum(A,2),A)./(size(A,2)-1)
```

### Explanation: Breaking it down to two steps

**Given**

```
>> A
A =
     1     1     1
     2     3     4
     4     5     6
```

**Step #1:** For each element in A, calculate the sum of all elements except the element itself -

```
>> bsxfun(@minus,sum(A,2),A)
ans =
     2     2     2
     7     6     5
    11    10     9
```

**Step #2:** Divide each element result by the number of elements responsible for the summations, which would be the `number of columns minus 1`, i.e. `(size(A,2)-1)` -

```
>> bsxfun(@minus,sum(A,2),A)./(size(A,2)-1)
ans =
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    3.5000    3.0000    2.5000
    5.5000    5.0000    4.5000
```

Comment: Unbelievably quick to answer... And correct. I didn't even get to start Matlab.. +1

Comment: really impressive, that was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @fn.mat Please wait a day or so before accepting an answer. The answers tend to be given more votes if you wait a bit and you might also get more/better answers...

Comment: `bsxfun` ninja strikes again.

Comment: @kkuilla Matlab should always be already started by the time you open StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 4):

Using your example:

```
[m,n]=size(A);
B=zeros(m,n);
for k=1:n
    B(:,k) = mean(A(:,[1:k-1 k+1:end]),2);
end
```

It may not be as quick or efficient as @Divakar's answer, but I tend to prefer `for` loop due to better readability. It might also make it easier to call a different function from `mean`.

Answer (score 3):

For an arbitrary function, you can use a vectorized approach if you don't mind using up more memory. Specifically, this requires generating a 3D array of size `r`x`c`x`c`, where `r` and `c` are the number of rows and columns of `A`.

```
f = @(x) prod(x,2); %// any function which operates on columns
c = size(A,2); %// number of columns
B = repmat(A, [1 1 c]);
B(:,1:c+1:end) = []; %// remove a different column in each 3D-layer
B = reshape(B, [], c-1, c); %// each 3D-layer of B contains a set of c-1 columns
result = f(B); %// apply function
result = squeeze(result); %// remove singleton dimension
```

As noted by Divakar in comments, anonymous functions tend to slow things down. It may be better to define the function `f` in a file.

Comment: Not sure if I have asked you this before, but here it - Do you think anonymous functions lead us to vectorized solutions? With what I have seen based on my little experience with them, they perform really slow, be it with `bsxfun` or `accumarray` and even just on their own.  Any thoughts or insights?

Comment: Good point. I also think they tend to be slow (I haven't tested really). The solution would still qualify as vectorized, because the function swallows the whole 3D array and produces (in a vectorized manner) the output. But I agree that if the result is slow, the purpose is defeated. A better approach would be to define `f` in a file

Comment: @Divakar A different matter would be calling `bsxfun` with an anonymous function (handle). That probably slows things down more; not (just) because of the function being anonymous, but because `bsxfun` probably works differently (internally) with an anonymous function than it does with one of its "built-ins"

Comment: @Divakar [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26219508/2586922) is what I meant (applied to `pdist` rather than `bsxfun`, but I think it's the same idea)

Comment: Agreed that `prod` must work in a vectorized manner here, so that's good there. Saving into a function file for more performance, agreed on that too based on my hunch, not really tested though. I think timing against the other loop based code could reveal something interesting here.