# The most optimized way of calculating distance between data in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization

I have n points in a 2D plane. I want to calculate the distance between each two points in c++. Position of m'th point in  the plan is (x(m),y(m)). This points changes during passing time. The number of time steps is equal to 10^5.
I wrote below code, but as n is a big number(5000) and I want to find the distance between points 10^5 times, I'm searching for the most optimized way to do that. Could anyone tell me what is the least time-consuming way to do that?

```
for(i=1;n;++)
   for(j=1;n;++)
      if (i>j)
         r(i,j)= r(j,i);
      else
         r(i,j)=sqrt((x(i)-x(j))^2+(y(i)-y(j))^2);
      end
   end
end
```

I know that, in Matlab, I can find this by using `bsxfun` function. I want also to know which one could calculate distances faster? Matlab or c++?

Comment: Even if you can avoid the `if` complexity will still be `O(n²)`.

Comment: You want to compute distances between all possible pairs of points. It'll be O(N^2) anyway. You can try to parallelize it to make things faster.

Comment: Yes, it is not a good way and I'm searching for the best way. Could you help me please? @Jarod42

Comment: Do you really need all the full distances?  You can usually make do with just the square of the distance for most comparison purposes, saving you calling the expensive sqrt

Comment: Good suggestion. Could you please see the edit to my question? @UKMonkey

Comment: The question regarding which is faster - matlab or c++?  Depends on your algorithm really.  You're asking the wrong questions I fear.  Perhaps you should rewind and try explaining why you need all the 10^5 distances in the first place?

Comment: Done!  is it clear now? @UKMonkey

Comment: If `n` is large enough, it might be faster get rid of your `if (i > j)` check and always compute the square root, because of cache misses. Better would be to compute the values on the upper triangle and use a block matrix algorithm to copy values to the other half.

Comment: ... I say this to demonstrate that writing high performance code is *very hard*, at least in part because requires that it requires very unfamiliar concerns. If you have a good library, you generally shouldn't try to outperform it unless you really have a good reason and know what you're doing. If you don't have that, better to use the library -- or learn how to use the library better.

Comment: Do you know a webpage that I can download efficient libraries of c++? @Hurkyl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Matlab, you have also [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) which does exactly that (but is not so fast), and you should also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777292/fast-algorithms-for-finding-pairwise-euclidean-distance).

---

About comparing Matlab and C first read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513071/performance-tradeoff-when-is-matlab-better-slower-than-c-c) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54927-which-has-high-speed-performance-matlab-or-c). Also keep in mind that Matlab, as a desktop program, requires knowing not only a general efficient way to implement your code but also the right way to do this in Matlab. One example is the difference between functions. Built-in functions are written in FORTRAN or C and run much faster then non-built-in functions. To know if a function is built-in, type:

```
which function_name
```

and check if you see "built-in" at the start of the output:

```
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\...)
```